# SharePoint Online - Remote Timer Job 401 Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I'm trying to create a timer job to run against my SharePoint Online tenant. I have been following this [video on Channel9](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/PnP-Core-Component-Remote-Timer-Job-Framework).

I believe I have everything set up correctly, however when it gets to executing:
[image]

It errors out with 401 Unauthorized. I am using the correct credentials as I am the only user on the tenant which I own, so it's the same credentials that I use to access O365 admin settings, etc.

Is there something I need to enable on my account to allow it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Solved**

When I was specifying the site to run against:
[image]

I had to use **https** for it to work. Silly mistake really:
[image]

It connects properly now.